# Merge several columns from two tables into one rows for id in the former table each

Tags: sql, postgresql, web, pivot, crosstab

If there are a table A and table B. The structure of them are below:

A :

```
id

1
2
```

B:

```
col_1    col_2

m         q
n         w
```

How Can I get the results of C which is below by SQL?

```
id     col_1   col_2    col_1  col_2 

 1       m     q        n      w
 2       m     q        n      w
```

---

For each data in Table B, they are related with the id in Table A. After concatenating the two table into Table C. once the id in Table C changes(which belongs to the id in Table A), the corresponding rows in Table C change. So in order to get the final Table C, there should be some calculations for getting each data in Table C(col_1, col_2, col_1 col_2)

Comment: Are the key names always "m" and "n"?  Are there always exactly two values resulting in four additional columns?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: No , There are may be multiple keys either from 0 to scores of them. IF the table A in conjuction with table B, We canget the table C with row_a rows and 2* row_b columns . We need to notice that the value 3 and 4 are just indication numbers , they will change according to the id in A. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood, you want to get all rows from table B and associate as columns with id from table A.

I think it is impossible with just a query (don't know if a procedure can solve it), but I have an approach that may help (I tested it on MySQL).

```
SELECT 
  `a`.`id`, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(`b`.`key`) AS `keys`, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(`b`.`value`) AS `values` 
FROM `a`, `b` 
GROUP BY `a`.`id` ASC;
```

As result we have:

```
 ---- ------ --------
| id | keys | values |
 ---- ------ --------
|  1 | m,n  | 3,4    |
|  2 | m,n  | 3,4    |
 ---- ------ --------
```

The first key in column keys and first value in column values refers to the first row of table b. The second refers to the second row and so on. This way you will just need to split on the delimiter ',' with some server side code.

I searched for the matching command from Postgres to the MySQL GROUP_CONCAT and found that **STRING_AGG** may do the same job.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer! I found that I have illustrated the problem wrong. The Table B should be the format belows: the columns keys and columns are all the data that related with the id in Table A, which means that if the number changes in Table A. The key and value will change in Table B. What I want to get is that for each id in Table C, the corresponding rows in Table B will be concatenated into one columns in Table C. Do you have any ideas to solving it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As long as you know in advance how many distinct `key` values can appear in B (and there are not too many), this should work:

```
select A.id, Once.key k1, Once.value v1, Twice.key k2, Twice.value v2
from A,(select * from B where B.key='m') Once,
(select * from B where B.key='n') Twice;
```

EDIT: This is the result obtained with the above query:

```
| ID | K1 | V1 | K2 | V2 |
--------------------------
|  1 |  m |  3 |  n |  4 |
|  2 |  m |  3 |  n |  4 |
```

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer! I found that I have illustrated the problem wrong. The Table B should be the format belows: the columns keys and columns are all the data that related with the id in Table A, which means that if the number changes in Table A. The key and value will change in Table B. What I want to get is that for each id in Table C, the corresponding rows in Table B will be concatenated into one columns in Table C. Do you have any ideas to solving it? Thanks

Comment: Please see my latest comments. Thanks.

Comment: @storage_pooling Can you provide a more explicit example? I can't see what you are trying to do exactly, sorry.

Comment: Hi @neutrino, I am so sorry that I havn't login stackoverflow for so long time. I have solved the issues. Thanks